# Excel VBA - Iterate Columns and Autofill if Cell Has Formula

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with this code?  I am trying to iterate through a database in excel to automatically fill down formulas to the last row.

```
Sub AutoFillFormulas()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim i As Integer

LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastColumn
  If Cells(4, i).HasFormula = True Then    
    Cells(4, i).Select    
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(4, i), Cells(LastRow, i)), Type:=xlFillDefault
  End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Update: So I think I have figured out a solution.  I believe the problem was with the Autofill code.  I switched to copy paste special and it started to work.  Unfortunately, it was very slow in the beginning.  After using an array the code ran much faster.  Thanks for the help!

I am very new to VBA by the way...

```
Sub AutoFillFormulas()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim vData() As Variant


LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

vData = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Value

For i = 1 To LastColumn

    If Cells(4, i).HasFormula = True Then
        Cells(4, i).Copy
        Range(Cells(4, i), Cells(LastRow, i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    End If
Next i

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Value = vData

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is going wrong?  What is your error message, and what triggers it?

Comment: I am not exactly sure.  The code does not produce an error message.  It works perfectly in some columns, but not in others.  I ran a msgbox for LastRow (902) and LastColumn (1844).  The code works in column G, it pulls the formula from G4 to G942.  However, in column CS and many others it does not work.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: "However, in column CS and many others it does not work".  How does it now work?  What is happening that shouldn't or is not happening that should.  BE SPECIFIC!

Comment: What happens if you try running the code just on one of the columns that's not working by commenting out the For and Next lines and filling in the column reference?

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster if you use

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

at the beginning and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = true
```

at the end of the code to avoid excessive screen refresh.